# Global frame of local costmap and goal accuracy

Tags: ros, navigation, frame, costmap, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm confused about global frame of local costmap. I'm trying with sbpl and pose follower. Since I want to follow the global plan as close as possible, I tried to change global frame of local costmap to `map`. It follows path reasonably however it jumps and sometimes collides due to jump. On the other hand to get rid of jumps when I switch to `odom` frame in local costmap, this time a considerable offset is seen especially when robot reaches the goal. End of global plan and the robot pose are apart 5-10 cm.

How can I get rid of this error at goal but follow the global path as close as possible? Is there a problem with my interpretation of global frames of costmaps?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263187/global-frame-of-local-costmap-and-goal-accuracy/) by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pose_follower has two parameters that control the goal tolerance:

`tolerance_trans` (default 0.02) and

`tolerance_rot` (default 0.04).

So if you have not changed these parameters, it is normal that your robot is 5-10 cm apart from a goal when it "reaches" it.
Anyway, keep in mind that an error of 10cm is quite small and acceptable in many applications.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Synedx](https://answers.ros.org/users/30641/synedx/) on 2017-06-07**:
However when I use `map` as global frame of my local costmap, it always end up with a smaller error than the configuration with `odom`. Is there a relation between goal error and local costmap global frame?